# SpeechRecognizer | What happend (nothing happend) after say nothing?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, nsspeechrecognizer

I dont find an answer on google or i dont get the right words for it.

So the SpeechRecognizer works fine. 
But when i hear the beep (i use it without the google dialog) and i say nothing for about 3 seconds or more, its like the recognizer do nothing and fade away, no second beep to hear, no onResult(), no EndofSpeech.

So what happend when the Recognizer is listening and you say nothing? Which method get fired?

EDIT: After all it works, big thanks to OpiateFuchs and his realy good comments and answers. I edit the simplified code that way, that you guys can see how to make it.
onPartialResult() is called often even if you say nothing, but when this happen the partialResult String is empty, so if its empty you know nothing was spoken.
(Idea from OpiateFuchs)

Thats my simplified Code which is important for the Recognizer:

```
public Constructor (){
        speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
        speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recogIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recogIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "de");
        speech.startListening();
}

public void startListening(){
    speech.startListening(recogIntent);
    if(timerRunning==false){
        setcdt();
        mCountDownTimer.start();
        timerRunning=true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Toast.makeText(c, "work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    //too see if its called
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {

}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

    Toast.makeText(c, matches.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    speech.cancel();
    analyse(matches.get(0));
    m.next(); //calls the Recognizer again

}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
ArrayList<String> matches = partialResults
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

    if(matches.get(0).length() == 0){
        m.tv.append("nothing"); //show on textview

    }
    else{
        m.tv.append("cancel timer "); //show on textview
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        hasSpoken = true;
        timerRunning = false;
    }

}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

}

//innerclass
public class FinishSpeechRecognizerTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public FinishSpeechRecognizerTimer(long startTime, long interval){
        super(startTime,interval);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(){
        timerRunning = false;
        if (hasSpoken==false){
            m.tv.append("nospeak ");
            speech.cancel();
            m.tv.append("listen again after no speak ");
            startListening();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinish){

    }
}

public void setcdt(){
    startTime = 5000;
    interval = 4000; //want no onTick - interval > startTime
    timerRunning = false;
    hasSpoken = false;
    mCountDownTimer = new FinishSpeechRecognizerTimer(startTime, interval);
}
```

Comment: maybe you could make a countdown timer and close the dialog....

Comment: But how handle the google recognizer the situation if he hear nothing? There must be something, some method or error..

Comment: please clearify, do you mean if the dialog doesn´t recognize your speech or do you mean if you say nothing, the dialog has to recognize that nothing is said?

Comment: if you mean the dialog should end up if no one speaks after a while, then I have to tell that this is not implemented. That´s sad but the speech recognizer needs some workaround on the android developer site. But as long as this is not done, you have to handle it by yourself.

Comment: Thats exactly what i mean. So but there must something happen when no one speak after all the recognizer has started. Somewhere there must be a stoplistining or a cancel otherwise he would listen "for ever" or?

Comment: I guess not. I think the recognizer would listen as long as the system stops it. As I said, it needs really a contemporary workaround from the android developer site. You can manipulate it on some side for example how long should it listen after words were spoken to be sure it doesn´t stop on speech pause. But this presupposes some words.

Comment: I guess, it is implemented in that way because of the general operability. For example the google app, where you can talk to, must be alive as long as possible. The user just says "Hello Google" to start it, so the listener listens all the time, also if it takes hours.

Comment: Mhh okay, thank you for the this detailed answer. I will get a solution with something like EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, too increase the time that there can be silence.

Comment: Yeah but as I suggested, these EXTRAS will presuppose some words. Even if you manipulate this value it will not stop listening if nothing is spoken.

Comment: I read the documentation and you may be right, so EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS would be better.

Comment: No, also the same behaviour, needs some words. There is no intent extra with that you can reach your goal, sorry. So really the best way is to do some kind of timer or handler that stops this recognizer programmatically. And this is not a hard task, this needs only a few lines of code so don´t worry about that.

Comment: If its that easy, can you give me a little example please..?

Comment: it depends on how you have implemented that. if You have started the speech recognition with an intent and startActivityForResult(), you should be able to cancel it with finishActivity(yourRequestCode). From Your code, I guess You have implemented SpeechRecognizer, for that I need a little bit to show an example...I have no IDE here to test it, so I ´m doing it from scratch...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108520/discussion-between-phil-and-opiatefuchs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this discussion I try to provide an example from scratch which should lead you into the right direction. As said in the comments, it seems that the `SpeechRecognition` does not stop from itself if nothing is said, so you simply could `implement` a `CountDownTimer` for example and finish the `SpeechRecognizer` after a certain time:

**make global `SpeechRecognizer` (like you have done), `boolean` and `CountdownTimer` `objects` :**

```
private SpeechRecognizer speech;   
private boolean hasSpoken=false;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private long startTime = 30000L;
private long interval = 1000L;
private boolean timerRunning = false;
```

**extend the `CountDownTimer class`:**

```
public class FinishSpeechRecognizerTimer extends CountDownTimer{

        public FinishSpeechRecognizerTimer(long startTime, long interval){
          super(startTime,interval);

           }

         @Override
         public void onFinish(){

             if(hasSpoken==false){
                speech.cancel();
            }

           timerRunning=false;

          }

         @Override
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinish){

           //do whatever you want to do

       }
}
```

**initialize**

```
speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(yourContext);
mCountDownTimer = new FinishSpeechRecognizerTimer(startTime, interval);
```

**start it and at the same time start the `CountDownTimer`:**

```
speech.startListening(recogIntent);
if(timerRunning==false){
mCountDownTimer.start();
timerRunning=true;
}
```

And as soon as something is spoken, set the `boolean value` `hasSpoken` to `true` and `cancel` the timer:

```
@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
   hasSpoken=true;
   mCountDownTimer.cancel();
   timerRunning=false;
}
```

As I said, it´s from scratch, can´t guarantee that this is working. This example starts the `CountDownTimer` for 30 seconds and checks every second if something is spoken. How long you want to wait is up to you.

### EDIT

Turns out that in some cases the onBeginOfSpeech() method is called multiple times without anybody is speaking. For everyone who is interested:

instead of doing that stuff in `onBeginOfSpeech()`, you can use the method `onPartialResult():`

```
@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULT_RECOGNITION);
 if(matches.size()==0){

        hasSpoken=false;

 }else{

  hasSpoken=true;
  mCountDownTimer.cancel();
       timerRunning=false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, the idea works but there is a problem with the google recognizer. The method onBeginningOfSpeech is fired so often, even if i say nothing, that the timer becomes useless. So its no problem with your code, it a google-problem.

Comment: Yeah, that´s a poor API for such a cool feature. Other possible solution is to set the countdowntimer to one or two minutes and catch the partial results in onPartialResult(). In reality, no one will wait  two minutes until he wants to speak. And if, then You can make a dialog to inform the user that it will stoppped because nothing was spoken. in OnPartialResults You can set the boolean to true or false. Just an idea.

Comment: I tested that too, but its the same like OnBeginningOfSpeech. OnPartialResults is fired too often even If i say nothing. Its not that thing that i want to wait that long (about Minutes and more). The Problem is when i dont speak immediately when i hear the beep, the recognizer will not record. (like when i beginn speaking about 3 seconds after beep, the recognizer dont "recognize" anymore)

Comment: have You tried to get the results onPartialResult()? If it works correctly, there should be an empty array, so then you can be sure there is nothing spoken. something like `if (result.size() = 0){hasSpoken=false}else{hasSpoken=true}`